# What is this unicode invisible character?

Tags: unicode, character, invisible

While trying to parse some unicode text strings, I'm hitting an invisible character that I can't find any definition for. If I paste it in to a text editor and show invisibles, I can see that it looks like a bullet point (• alt-8), and by copy/pasting them, I can see it has an effect like a space or tab, but it's none of those.

I need to test for it, something like...

```
 if(uniChar == L'\t')
```

But of course I need to provide something to match to.

It has bytes 0xc2 0xa0 in UTF-8.

If no-one has a definition, is there any devious way to test for something I can't define!?

(I happen to be using NSStrings in Objective-C, OSX, Xcode, but I don't think that has any bearing.)

Comment: Where is it coming from? What are the actual bytes (and in what encoding?)

Comment: Can you output the binary value of that string/character?

Comment: Can't you display the contents of memory of uniChar to see what data is there?

Comment: Print all your character input next to it's integer equivalent (use casting) to find the integer equivalent, which is easy to check for?

Comment: It's UTF8 encoding within some actor scripts in plain text files. Thanks for the great suggestions, I'll try them and report back.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_character#Spaces_in_Unicode

Comment: OK, as bytes it is: \xc2\xa0\, ints in memory: B0 A9 51 00 01 00 00 .Thanks for the link Hans, it describes it as:"U+00B7 183 Middle dot Basic Latin · interpunct, used in text processors. HTML also: &middot;   Still have no idea how to reproduce it on a keyboard, or how anyone ever entered it. But at least I can test for it now.

Comment: C2 A0 is not U+00B7. U+00B7 is C2 B7. What are "ints in memory"?

Comment: I displayed the contents of memory for the variable arranged as 4-byte blocks, wasn't sure if it was useful or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bytes C2 A0 in UTF-8 encode [U+00A0 ɴᴏ-ʙʀᴇᴀᴋ sᴘᴀᴄᴇ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), which can be used, for example, to display combining marks in isolation. It is `&nbsp;` as a named HTML entity. It is almost the same as a U+0020 sᴘᴀᴄᴇ, except it prevents line breaks before or after it, and acts as a numerical separator for bidirectional layout.

The dot you see when you ask a text editor to show invisibles just happens to be what glyph the text editor chose to display spaces. It does not mean the character in question is U+00B7 ᴍɪᴅᴅʟᴇ ᴅᴏᴛ, which is definitely not invisible.

In code, if you have it as a `unichar`, you can compare it to `L'\x00A0'`.

Comment: This answer makes use of &nbsp;!

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer. It makes sense now, I believe the script was originally entered in a web page, and copied and pasted from there.